Middle top pearless pear tree dead
Our pearless pear tree started losing leaves and the middle top branches were bare at the end of fall last year.  This year the leaves have all came out except for the middle top and top right side of the tree.  Do we cut out the dead branches?  Do we need a specific food to feed it?  Any help is appreciated

A dead branch will never regrow.

Cutting back the dead branches is advisable.

I'm very sorry to hear about the condition of your Pear tree. Here are some suggestions that might help -

Pruning - Since the branches are dead it is okay to prune them to avoid any further problems (i.e. any disease or pest infestation).
Test The Soil - You should conduct a soil test and see if there's a lack of certain nutrients and feed your plant accordingly.
Check For Other Problems - Check if your Pear tree is showing other signs of a disease or pest problem.

These are some of the things you should do to prevent any further damage to the plant. Moreover, it is a good idea to consult a local arborist to get specific advice based on your local climate and conditions.

I planted a regular pear tree and it did well for a few years then the leaves on some of the branches turned black and died. Eventually the branch died off too and had no more life.
I live in Sacramento, CA and in our area we have what is commonly known as "fire blight" That is what took our tree. Not sure if the fruitless pear is as susceptible to this blight but you may want to research it.
